# Creating A Tree and Adding Values

Tags: java, tree

Hey guys,
I have implemented a tree. To me, it should work properly, but since I am here, it does not. For the record, my tree is of type City, which has three fields, one of which is name as you will see. Take a look at my codes:

```
void add(City added, City parent){
//added is what is going to be added and child of parent. I first find parent in tree
//search method is coming after
    TreeNode<City> parentNode = search(parent,this);
    if (parentNode.hasLeftChild() && parentNode.getLeftChild().getCity().equals(parent))
        parentNode = parentNode.getLeftChild();
    else if (parentNode.hasNextSibling() && parentNode.getNextSibling().getCity().equals(parent))
        parentNode = parentNode.getNextSibling();
    else if (!parentNode.hasLeftChild())
        parentNode.setLeftChild(new TreeNode<City>(added,null,null));
    else {
        TreeNode<City> next = parentNode.getLeftChild();
        while(next.hasNextSibling())
            next = next.getNextSibling();
        next.setNextSibling(new TreeNode<City>(added,null,null));
    }
}

public TreeNode<City> search(City parent, TreeNode<City> t){
    if (t.getCity().equals(parent))
        return t;
    else if (t.hasLeftChild())
        return search(parent,t.getLeftChild());
    else 
        return search(parent,t.getNextSibling());
}
```

I am keep taking nullpointerexception and have no idea what to do. Anyone has better idea to search for an element and add it. Or at least a web-site for me to learn that shit???

Comment: And what is the stacktrace of the NPE? It should tell you the exact line of code that it occurs at, which makes troubleshooting this a heck of a lot easier for everyone.

Comment: Yeah, I see where the problem is. When I called methods for leftchild, if the final child is not the one i am looking for, it gives error. I want to know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You have to test for the base case where your tree is null, so that the Node you are trying to add will really become the root of the tree.

Comment: I have guaranteed that is not gonna happen. Tree will be created in the main with one city in it